# How to get the name of a day of the week for a specific date using ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, date

I'm sure there's a simple method or function out there to do this (at least I'm hoping there is). I want to return the name of a day of the week for a specific date using ActionScript.

For example, if I provide "2/2/2011" as a parameter, it should return "Wednesday". What's the best way to make this happen?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to butterbrot's answer and some more digging with the `DateFormatter`, I've found two solutions to my original problem. While both of them will work, I'm curious to know if anyone can think of a reason why one would be preferred over the other. Any thoughts?

Comment: When using the `DateFormatter`, you get **automatic localization support** for all locales you compiled into the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some more digging, it turns out the `DateFormatter` can do this.

[From Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html):

**The `DateFormatter`:**

```
<mx:DateFormatter id="dayOfWeekFormatter" formatString="EEEE" />
```

**Using `dayOfWeekFormatter`:**

```
dayOfWeekFormatter.format(myDate);
```

Answer (score 6):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#day

```
var dayNames:Array = ['Sunday', 'Monday', ...]
var dayName:String = dayNames[myDate.day];
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Much appreciated. Is there no built-in Actionscript function that will do this? When you call the `.toDateString()` method on a Date object it will return "Wed Feb 2 2011", so it knows how to get the day from somewhere...